# How to find the last element of a sub-group of elements in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have a dataframe that ID:3 is repeated several time. The first time that it is repeated is a sub-group with index 2,3,4 start indexing from 0 (according to the example of df below). I am interested to record "index: 4" which is the last index from the first sub-group in which ID:3 is repeated.

```
data = {'ID': ['1', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '2', '5', '3', '3', '6', '3', '3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
3 sub-groups whereID=3 are:
Index  ID
2       3
3       3
4       3

Index  ID
8       3
9       3

Index  ID
11      3
12      3
I wanted to record Index of 4 which is the last index in the first subgroup.
```

I have tried the code below. But I can record only the last index of ID:3 which is 12.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

max_indx = ([])

for indx, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row['ID'] ==str(3): 
        max_indx = np.append(max_indx, indx) 
        max_element = np.amax(max_indx)

print('index: ', max_element)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you expect is unclear. If you want to know the last index of each subgroup, you can use:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift(-1))], axis=1)
    ID     ID
0    1   True  # <- last index of first group '1'
1    2   True  # <- last index of first group '2'
2    3  False
3    3  False
4    3   True  # <- last index of first group '3'
5    4   True  # <- last index of first group '4'
6    2   True  # <- last index of second group '2'
7    5   True  # <- last index of first group '5'
8    3  False
9    3   True  # <- last index of second group '3'
10   6   True  # <- last index of first group '6'
11   3  False
12   3   True  # <- last index of third group '3'
```

So if you want to extract these indexes:

```
>>> df.loc[df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift(-1)), 'ID']
0     1
1     2
4     3
5     4
6     2
7     5
9     3
10    6
12    3
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

And if you only interest to the last index of the first subgroup:

```
>>> df.loc[df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift(-1)), 'ID'].drop_duplicates()
0     1
1     2
4     3
5     4
7     5
10    6
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Comment: I have edited the question so it is more undrestandable. @Corralien  ! Your answer is not what I meant.

Comment: Does `df.loc[df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift(-1)), 'ID'].drop_duplicates().loc[lambda x: x == '3'].index` is what you expect?